# How can I pass the spider?

Tags: ios, finding-teddy

I'm running Finding Teddy 1.0.1 and I stuck in the spider challenge.
He sing to me some notes that is not on my list, And when I sing them to him,
He is not "recognize" them.
Which notes I should exactly sing to him?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the spider puzzle in the end of the game, "Tarant".

**NOTE:** Each note has the shape and represents a letter, the notes are organized alphabetically from A-Z.

To solve this last puzzle you need to have a dialogue with the Tarant by reusing a few of the messages you've picked up throughout the game

**PUZZLE SOLUTION:**

Tarant: HELLO
Respond to Tarant by repeating the notes to sing "HELLO" (Frog Puzzle)

Tarant: I AM SAD
Respond: HAPPY (Crying Monster Puzzle)

Tarant: I HAVE NO FRIEND
Respond: I AM YOUR FRIEND (Mother of Baby Spider)

Tarant: WHAT DO YOU WANT?
Respond: TEDDY

---

The other spider puzzle (not applicable, old answer)

To pass the spider challenge you don't need music, you need the **Jar with the Ant**.

If you and haven't captured the Ant, go back to place where it is and use the Jar to capture it.

Once you have it go to the place where the Spider is and **place the Ant in the web**.

In exchange, you will receive a Ball of Spider Thread.

Comment: I have used it already to lure the cat...

Comment: are you talking about the giant spider of the end then?

Comment: Of course, the other spider does not sing to you

Comment: @HashiramaSenju I've edited the answer with the correct solution